# Module 'discord' has no attribute 'ui'

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, discord.py

I have a problem with my code from my discord bot. When I run the program I get an error message, but I have all imports up to date. Can someone help me please, because I really have no idea how to fix this . If you have any more questions just write in.

Here is the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'ui'
```

And Here is my Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_ui import ButtonInteraction, Button, ButtonStyle, UI

intent = discord.Intents.default()
intent.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intent=intent)

role_id = 938465872098512956
guild_id = 938215477157703771 

class RoleButton(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            label="Verifiziere dich hier!", 
            style=discord.enums.ButtonStyle.blurple,
            custom_id="interaction:RoleButton",
        )
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        user = interaction.user

        role = interaction.guild.get_role(role_id)

        if role is None:
            return

        if role not in user.roles:
            await user.add_roles(role)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f" Du bist nun verifiziert!", ephemeral=True)

        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"❌ Du bist bereits verifiziert!", ephemeral=True)

BILD_URL = ""
BESCHREIBUNG = "Test"

@bot.command()
async def post(ctx: commands.Context): # Command
    view = discord.ui.View(timeout=None)

    view.add_item(RoleButton())

    await ctx.send(f"{BILD_URL}")
    await ctx.send(f"{BESCHREIBUNG}", view=view)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ONLINE!")
    view = discord.ui.View(timeout=None)
    view.add_item(RoleButton())
    bot.add_view(view)

bot.run("")
```

Comment: You probably don't have discord.py 2.0 but 1.7.x You can upgrade via git using ``pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py``

Comment: Ty, that fixed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a button using discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72282144/how-to-make-a-button-using-discord-py)